# which Design Pattern can be used?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have 3 classes, they inherit from parent class. A parameter in the init method of the child classes is used to define in parent to set a parameter an define how a method is called.

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, marker):
        self.executeCode(marker)


class ClassA(Parent):

    def __init__(self, marker):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__("class_a")


class ClassB(Parent):

    def __init__(self, marker):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__("class b")


class ClassC(Parent):
    def __init__(self, marker):
        super(ClassC, self).__init__("class c")
```

Which is the best pattern to use here, to make it more pythonic?

Comment: Patterns are structures you discover in your code, or that you move towards. Come up with a concrete example of working code. Then submit it to [codereview.se].

Comment: It's hard to tell which design would be best without knowing what the classes are for, what `marker` is and what `executeCode` does. It would be interesting to see all the intents/responsibilities of your classes to see if a different design (perhaps composition instead of inheritance) would make more sense.

Comment: Probably the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).